# How to continue deploy if DynamoDb table already exists

Tags: lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I'd like to continue the deployment (or force) even if a resource already exists.

Atm I got this error:

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

     An error occurred while provisioning your stack: AvailableDynamoDbTable
     - Available already exists.
```

Comment: If your resource is not handled solely by that serverless application then you should not try to handle it. Either handle the resources in the CloudFormation stack that serverless creates or handle it where it was originally created.

Comment: @doorstuck, it is handled by serverless, but sometimes you need to recreate the table and now you need to remove all serverless, because this error always appear and you can´t deploy

Comment: Why must the table be recreated? It sounds like it is not handled completely by serverless and the cloud formation stack and has its own life. Consider not managing the database with serverless in this case.
Only a database that is used entirely inside the serverless project and only there should be handled by the serverless project. If the database has external dependencies (someone else calls it) or someone else will recreate it, etc., then it should not be part of the serverless stack.
That is just my opinion and experience :)

Comment: What you need is `SkipIfExists: True` (https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183#issuecomment-962529842).

Answer (score 12):

**Backup the table and delete it. Restore once deployed.**

I had the same issue when I renamed my serverless project and tried to deploy. I had a table `tanks` that was being used again.
It failed with the following

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 An error occurred: TanksDynamoDbTable - tanks already exists in stack arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-central-1:592235674655:stack/colossal-dev/105693a8-77af-11e9-8f9e-2a86e4085a59.
```

I got it solved by making a backup of the **tanks** table, then deleting it.

1. Console > DynamoDB
2. On the left select Backups
3. Create backup > select Table from the dropdown and give it a name >
   Create
4. On the left select Tables
5. Check on Tanks > Delete

After deleting, one must wait for five minutes because the caches are cleaned periodically and not immediately. 
After that, I tried `serverless deploy` and it worked. 
After this, you will need to restore the backed up database.

1. On the left select Backups
2. Check the backed up table > Restore
3. Type the same name for the table as before, as the new table name.
4. Restore table
   Restored database takes some time appear so wait for perhaps five minutes or may be longer.

Comment: This actually worked, even though I had to remove the newly deployed table before being able to restore it again.

Comment: Of course is going to work, you guys are deleting the table, then deploying.
The problem to solve is: when deploying first time, then again. It should not throw.

Answer (score 11):

This question is fairly old, but still shows up in the top 5 results in Google, so here is a bit of an insight:
It's a good idea to split up your serverless stack into multiple services, each having its own `serverless.yml` file. One for your API and lambdas, one for your DynamoDB. This way you can deal with them separately and update your lambdas without touching your DB.
Here is a great guide on that:

1. https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/organizing-serverless-projects.html
2. https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/dynamodb-as-a-serverless-service.html
3. https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/deploying-multiple-services-in-serverless.html

Comment: this is a good advice but isnt the correct solution. Since it dont really solves the problem. As you can see the long discussion in the forum.

Comment: @Marckaraujo what forum are you referring to? Can you please link to it?

Answer (score 4):

Its not possible atm with Serverless@1.6.1.

I just open an issue on github: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183

Please, everyone that need this feature, join this discussion.

I will update here with news.

Comment: Any news on the issue?

Comment: Update: [issue closed as wontfix](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183#issuecomment-696051996).

Answer (score 2):

have struggled with this for 2 weeks  together with other deployment issues

now i would say - table alredy exists or queue does not exist and similar
is all about you are trying to violate stack 'security':

- serverless app relies on CloudFormation
- if your serverless deployment tries to manage resource which does not
  belong to it - you will have 'already exists...(but not yours);

since i re-deployed all from scratch and restored dbs, i have almost always stable deployment with changes in resources, till some colleague
does something manually)

so to not have such issues would better:

- to nod add delete modify resources manually
- name them to not overlap (like  dev-Table/prod-Table)
- use resources as external to stack resources with arns (or exported tames with serverless outputs);
- play with importing resources (resource groups) to your stack

Answer (score 1):

If test env you can go to AWS console delete existed table, So If you want to create multiple lambda functions share some tables you should create one serverless only handle Dynamodb, and remaining services don't contain any Dynamodb config.

If you want all lambda same API Gateway you can add `apiGateway` below provider as example below

for example:

- serverless A: DynamoDB and public endpoint `/`, API Gateway have
  `restApiId:xxxxx`, `restApiRootResourceId:yyyyyy`
- serverless B: User service and public endpoint `/users`
- serverless C: Vehicle service and public endpoint `/vehicle`

## serverless.yml serverless A

```
resources:
  Resources:
    VehiclesDynamoDbTable:
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
          AttributeDefinitions:
            -
              AttributeName: id
              AttributeType: S
          KeySchema:
            -
              AttributeName: id
              KeyType: HASH
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1
          TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_VEHICLE_TABLE}

     UsersDynamoDbTable:
        Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
        DeletionPolicy: Retain
        Properties:
          AttributeDefinitions:
            -
              AttributeName: id
              AttributeType: S
          KeySchema:
            -
              AttributeName: id
              KeyType: HASH
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: 1
            WriteCapacityUnits: 1
          TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_USER_TABLE}
```

## serverless.yml serverless B

```
provider:
  apiGateway
    restApiId: xxxxx # REST API resource ID. Default is generated by the framework
    restApiRootResourceId: yyyyyy # Root resource, represent as / path
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        Resource: "*"
```

## serverless.yml serverless C

```
provider:
  apiGateway
    restApiId: xxxxx # REST API resource ID. Default is generated by the framework
    restApiRootResourceId: yyyyyy # Root resource, represent as / path
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
        - dynamodb:DescribeTable
        Resource: "*"
```

Comment: I used a variation of this, Basically my serverless A remained untouched, it creates and manages the DynamoDB. It also runs code and does stuff.

For Serverless B, C ... I commented out the resources: section and used the `Resource: "*"` snippet.


`Resource: "*"` is the real take-away from all of this. I believe that it would also enable us to use DyanamoDB tables that were set up manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and remove the `xxxDynamoDbTable` in `serverless.yml` that item already exists in your Dynamodb could work. you don't have to `Resources` it again. :D

Comment: That doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid deleting the table, then it's best to stop managing the AWS Resource as part of your lambda function stack. Instead, you can import the production table resource from some external source.

The serverless team [Won't Fixed a feature request](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183#issuecomment-696051996) to fix this:

> What we deal with here, is not a limitation of a Framework per se, but limitation of CloudFormation through which Framework deploys configured services.
>
> While what's being requested seems now "kind of" possible with CloudFormation (via combination of handling of `DeletionPolicy` and introduced not far ago [import resources capability](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-existing-stack.html)). Trying to tackle this generically, seems far from trivial. It may require tons of work (and new issues to fight with), as already [observed by @kennu](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3183#issuecomment-673601954).
>
> Due to implied complexity this doesn't seem as right direction. It seems more reasonable to agree that resources as configured with a Serverless service are inseparable part of a service and are meant to also be removed with service (when we remove it with `sls remove`). For cases when we do not find that acceptable, we should rather configure resources in question externally. Note that Framework in many places allows to attach to *existing* (created and configured externally) resources.

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure you aren't accidentally creating a new instance of the CloudFormation stack, perhaps with a different name.  If you are deploying using the same name as a stack that already exists, it should simply be updating everything.

However, if you are inadvertently creating a new stack because the name changed, for example "my-app-prod" vs "my-app-production", this failure could occur because your "my-app-prod" already created the tables and "my-app-production" is trying to recreate those same tables which would fail since they already exist.